# In stat_summary_hex, why do hexagons overlap if z is a factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the data set below, thing1 is numeric, and thing2 is a factor (but otherwise identical to thing1). For simplicity, the summary function is just the max value in the bin. When the z element is a factor, the hexagons overlap. Anyone know why?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hexbin)
DF=data.frame(xpos=rnorm(1000),
              ypos=rnorm(1000),
              thing1=rep(1:9,length.out=100),
              thing2=as.factor(rep(1:9,length.out=100)))
ggplot(DF, aes(x=xpos, y=ypos, z=thing1)) +  
  stat_summary_hex(fun=function(x){x[which.max(x)]})
ggplot(DF, aes(x=xpos, y=ypos, z=thing2)) +  
  stat_summary_hex(fun=function(x){x[which.max(x)]})
```

[image: thing1]
[image: thing2]

Comment: It looks like a bug. I reproduce the same behavior only with `stat_binhex`. I mean `ggplot(DF, aes(x=xpos, y=ypos, z=thing2)) +     stat_binhex()`. Maybe you should contact the package maintainer.

Comment: It looks like hexagons are overlapping because ggplot has created a new layer for each factor level in the same plot. You can see the matching layer hexagons do not overlap each other. But I'm not sure how to constrain the xlim/ylims for the binning, which is I think what is needed.

Comment: But why would you calculate maximum of a factor ... isn't that already a "mistake"?

Comment: @Яaffael, one could replace the function with one appropriate for factors--maybe highest frequency level (i.e., mode).

Answer (score 0):

There are, to my knowledge, two functions in R to hexbin: hexBinning and geom_hex in the fMultivar and ggplot2 packages respectively. And both parametrize the centers of the hexagons according to the coordinates of hte lower-leftmost point in the sample.

It means that if you split your sample (according to a factor or, in my case, inside a mapreduce job) your hexagons become eccentric.

So I implemented my own hexbin function that assumes (0,0) as the center of the grid (i.e., if there were points around (0,0), the corresponding hexagon would be centered there) and requires just r (the radious of the hexagon) as parameter.

The implementation is [here](http://www.datanalytics.com/blog/2013/10/28/contando-hexagonos-en-paralelo/) (sorry, text is in Spanish!). Moreover, my implementation has no explicit loops: it is fully vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the setting where `thing2` is a factor, this discrete variable gets picked up by the automatic grouping, so you're effectively plotting `nlevel(thing2)` groups, each with their own coordinates for hex bins. To overrule the automatic grouping, you can manually set `group = 1`.<

To show that they are the same, below is the plot with the numeric `thing1`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

DF <- data.frame(
  xpos   = rnorm(1000),
  ypos   = rnorm(1000),
  thing1 = rep(1:9, length.out=100),
  thing2 = as.factor(rep(1:9, length.out=100))
)

ggplot(DF, aes(x = xpos, y = ypos, z = thing1)) +  
  stat_summary_hex(fun = function(x) x[which.max(x)])
```

[image]

Next we plot `thing2`, but set the group manually. The plot is identical to the `thing1` plot.

```r
ggplot(DF, aes(x = xpos, y = ypos, z = thing2, group = 1)) +  
  stat_summary_hex(fun = function(x) x[which.max(x)])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

(as time of writing current ggplot2 3.4.0 has a bug with hex bins, reproduce with a different version)